# Filter included property using EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently creating a beer website and I want to filter beers by style using a simple query like so:

```
IQueryable<Beer> result = this.context.Beers
                                      .Include(b => b.Brewery)
                                      .Include(b => b.Style)
                                      .Include(b => b.Reviews)
                                      .ThenInclude(r => r.User)
                                      .Where(b => b.IsDeleted == false);

if (searchCriteria != null)
{
    if (type == "Name")
    {
        result = result.Where(b => b.Name.Contains(searchCriteria));
    }
    else if (type == "Style")
    {
        result = result.Where(b => b.Style.Name.Contains(searchCriteria));
    }
    else
    {
        result = result.Where(b => b.Brewery.Name.Contains(searchCriteria));
    }
}
```

However when it is executed I get 0 results since the query hasn't been materialized and the Style property are null, even though they have been included.

How can I get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To materialize the query, just add `.ToList()`.

So, at the end of the snippet, you can use

```
result.ToList()
```

Be careful though, some of the conditions in your `Where` clauses can lead to potential performance problems. Don't forget to create indexes, especially if your db starts to be big.

Note that you should not materialize using `ToList()` too early (before the search criterias) either, because that would mean taking all the table in memory before filtering.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but it should be possible to generate your query first before finally materializing your query with the eager loading. That way you get the database to do the heavy lifting rather than .Net.

```
IQueryable<Beer> result = this.context.Beers.Where(b => b.IsDeleted == false);

if (searchCriteria != null)
{
    if (type == "Name")
    {
        result = result.Where(b => b.Name.Contains(searchCriteria));
    }
    else if (type == "Style")
    {
        result = result.Where(b => b.Style.Name.Contains(searchCriteria));
    }
    else
    {
        result = result.Where(b => b.Brewery.Name.Contains(searchCriteria));
    }
}

List<Beer> materialisedResults = result
                                   .Include(b => b.Brewery)
                                   .Include(b => b.Style)
                                   .Include(b => b.Reviews)
                                   .ThenInclude(r => r.User).ToList();
```

Comment: While your code will work and this solves OP's problem, having the `Include` before or after the `Where` has no impact, in my experience. The load will be done when the query is materialized anyway, i.e. when the `.ToList()` occur.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if all data has been coming on the result or not, then .ToList() will execute to store all of the data in the result, then you can query.

```
var result = this.context.Beers
                         .Include(b => b.Brewery)
                         .Include(b => b.Style)
                         .Include(b => b.Reviews)
                         .ThenInclude(r => r.User)
                         .Where(b => b.IsDeleted == false).ToList();

            if (searchCriteria != null)
            {
                if (type == "Name")
                {
                    result = result.Where(b => b.Name.Contains(searchCriteria));
                }
                else if (type == "Style")
                {
                    result = result.Where(b => b.Style.Name.Contains(searchCriteria));
                }
                else
                {
                    result = resultWhere(b => b.Brewery.Name.Contains(searchCriteria));
                }
            }
```

Comment: This will cause all the beer table to be loaded in memory, and then the filter are applied. i.e. the query won't have any of the `Where` clauses (except for the `isDeleted == false`)

Comment: That is my concern as well. The db has 2500 beers and I don't want to load all of them before the filter and before the indexing.